# Possible to animate a View inside a ViewGroup inside a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-animation

I have a class that extends LinearLayout defined in main.xml. Programmatically I create x number of classes that extend ViewGroup. I have overridden canAnimate() to return true. Inside of that there are some more views also created programmatically. What I am trying to do is tap on one of those nested child views and have it animate (y-axis rotation ObjectAnimator). At the end of animation I hide the tapped view in the onAnimationEnd listener.

The touch event works, and I can see the view that was tapped hide after the given duration of the animation. The problem is that the view doesn't actually animate. If I use the same animation code on the ViewGroup extension, I can see that animate as you would expect.

What it seems like is that you can't animate child views that are nested more than 2 levels deep. Can anyone confirm this or give an example of how to animate a View of a ViewGroup of a LinearLayout?

This is in Honeycomb.

Thanks.

Update:
I can nest 4 LinearLayouts and a View in XML and see it animate. I changed the class that extends ViewGroup to extend LinearLayout but still no animation with the child view. What could be set inflating a view that I'm not setting programmatically to allow animation of children?

```
public class MyViewGroup extends ViewGroup implements ViewGroup.OnTouchListener {

    private View viewToAnimate;

    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setup(context);
    }

    public MyViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setup(context);
    }

    public MyViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setup(context);
    }

    private void setup(Context context)
    {
        viewToAnimate = new View(context);
        viewToAnimate.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        viewToAnimate.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        viewToAnimate.setOnTouchListener(this);
        addView(viewToAnimate);    
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canAnimate()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // Left out for brevity
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        animateViewRotation();
        return true;
    }

    private Interpolator accelerator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    private Interpolator decelerator = new DecelerateInterpolator();
    private void animateViewRotation()
    {
            // Tried all of the following:
        /*
        ObjectAnimator rotationY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToAnimate, "rotationY", 0f, 90f);
        AnimatorSet translations = new AnimatorSet();
        translations.setDuration(1000);
        translations.play(rotationY);
        translations.start();
        */

        /*
        RotateAnimation ta = new RotateAnimation(0f, 90f, 0, 100);
        ta.setDuration(1000);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(ta);
        */


        // Copied/adapted from API Demos code
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewToAnimate, "rotationY", 0f, 90f);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        //animation.setInterpolator(accelerator);
        animation.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator anim) {
                viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        animation.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: I should note that a LayoutAnimation works, but only after the first onLayout, and didn't respond to calling start() after the view touch.